Timestamp several columns each separately
I'm trying to add a timestamp in column B when I edit column A, and in column E when I edit column D. These timestamps should show just the time, no date.
I tried this:
 /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e){
const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
sh.getRange ('M' + e.range.rowStart)
.setValue (new Date())
.setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMam/pm');
}

But this code will timestamp column M every time I edit any cell in the row, instead of only timestamping A to B and D to E.
How do I add a timestamp only when certain columns are edited, and put those timestamps in a different column depending on which column was edited?

Office Script for Excel and Apps Script for Google Sheets. Decide what you are using. Btw from the code it seems you are using Google sheets.

You can check which column was edited and add your timestamp in col B or D as followed:
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1 || e.range.getColumn() == 3) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1)
        .setValue(new Date())
        .setNumberFormat('HH:MMam/pm');
  }
 }


Hello I'm so sorry, may I know where will I place the column that I need the timestamp for?
I am trying to input data on Column A and timestamped on Column B. I don't want to add timestamp on Column B when I edit a cell in Column E, if that makes sense.
If possible, can you make a specific script for me assuming that A1 is what I need to be timestamped?
I would really appreciate it!

No worries!
The current script adds a timestamp in Col B when Col A is modified, and timestamp in Col D when Col C is modified. The timestamp will be placed in the same row the data was modified. (If I modify A7, B7 will have the timestamp).
I am not sure where you want to add your timestamp, but if you only want in col B when A is modified, here is a new script:

/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) { // Check if the edit was in col A
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn() + 1)
.setValue(new Date())
.setNumberFormat('HH:MMam/pm'); // Apply timestamp in col B, same row as edited cell
}
}

There are many tried and tested timestamp scripts out there. You may want to use one of them instead of writing your own from scratch.
To do what you ask with my yetAnotherTimestamp_ script, use these parameters with the script:
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheets: /^(.+|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i,
        watch: {
          columns: ['A', 'D',],
          values: /./i,
          rowStart: 2,
          rowEnd: +Infinity,
        },
        stamp: {
          columns: ['B', 'E',],
          format: 'hh:mm am/pm',
          overwrite: true,
          eraseOnDelete: false,
        },
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]

To add more columns, edit the two columns arrays. To choose which sheets and trigger values the script reacts to, edit the relevant
regular expressions.
The script I linked is optimized and uses the event object e. It will run faster than shorter scripts that use e.range.getColumn() and e.range.getRow(). See these onEdit(e) optimization tips.

Hi, so I used this and edited as advised but I encountered this error:
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' line: 4 file: Code.gs
This is how I input it:
// [START modifiable parameters]
{
sheets: /^(.+|Sheet3|Sheet4|Sheet5|Sheet6|Sheet7|Sheet8|Sheet9)$/i,
watch: {
column: ['A'],
values: /./i,
rowStart: 2,
rowEnd: +Infinity,
},
stamp: {
column: ['B'],
format: 'hh:mm am/pm',
overwrite: true,
eraseOnDelete: false,
},
},
// [END modifiable parameters]

The expression you quote looks like it should work fine when pasted inside the parameters section of the yetAnotherTimestamp_ script. To learn more, see Apps Script at Stack Overflow.
